Does stargazer still support starprep?
I am trying to produce regression tables with robust standard errors but keep getting errors whenever I use starprep to get standard errors. The code was working well a few weeks ago but now I keep getting an error saying "starprep" cannot be found
I expected a html tabke but no response. Here is my code
stargazer(tax_GD, tax_GDfe, type = "html",
      title = "Regression of <em> Tax </em> on GDPppg",

      notes.label = "P-Values",

      notes = "Standard errors are robust",

      df = FALSE,

      notes.align = "l",

      covariate.labels = "GDP",

      dep.var.labels = c("Taxes"),  # Ensure labels are correctly set

      se = starprep(tax_GD, tax_GDfe, se_type = "stata"),  # Assuming 'dat$year' as clusters

      omit = c("iso3c", "year"),

      out = "fixed_effects_GDPTAX.html",

      add.lines = list(c('Fixed effects', 'No', 'Yes')))


do you have the package estimatr loaded/installed?
